# Annotations on a variable, inside a class

Tags: java, validation, annotations

Recently I saw an example of validating fields with annotations like:

```
Class Foo{
    @Min(2)
    int x;
}
```

I know I can access functions declared in annotation interfaces like:

```
//UPDATE: missing code
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Min {
    int x() default 0;
}

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Afoo {
    String msg() default "Oy!";
}

@Afoo(msg = "Hi!")
class Foo{
//    @Min(3)
    public int x;
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = Foo.class;
        Annotation an = c.getAnnotation(Afoo.class);
        Afoo a = (Afoo)an;

        System.out.println(a.msg());
    }

}
```

However, when I uncomment the line

```
//    @Min(3)
```

and make a new annotation interface called `Min`, I have an error saying:

> annotation type not applicable for this kind of declaration.

So even if I could access this function, how would I know it is related to `x`?

Comment: "So even if I could access this function, how would I know it is related to x?" - I don't understand the question.

Comment: Where/how is min defined?

Comment: The code here is not even valid Java. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the declaration of your own version of the `Min` annotation is itself annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`, the `@Target` is wrong. The `ElementType.TYPE` is [for classes, interfaces and enum declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html). You don't want to annotate types, you want to annotate a field `x`. Use

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
```

instead.